# preg_match cannot match string fetched from database

Tags: php

I have this string

> $s = 'FX67KU373 Confirmed. You have received USD85.00 from JANE DOE
>   44587398 on 4/11/14 at 5:48 PM New Tigo balance is USD92.00.Save money
>   on Tigo';

in my php script for testing purposes. In production,i am fetching strings from the database like this

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=app', 'root', '123456');

$fc = $dbh->prepare("select one from t_data where id = 1084");
$fc->execute();

$s = $fc->fetchColumn(0);

echo $s;
```

`s` displays the string i am fetching from the database which is the same as the one on my php script.However,when i

```
$matches = array();

preg_match('/from (.*?) on/', $s, $matches);

echo '<br/><br/>';
var_dump($matches);
```

`$matches` is empty for the string fetched from the database and not empty for the value in my script.Why is this the case?.

This is how the string from the database looks like exactly

```
$s = 'FX67KU373 Confirmed.
You have received USD85.00 from
JANE DOE 44587398
on 4/11/14 at 5:48 PM
New Tigo balance is USD92.00.Save money on Tigo';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your String (in the code) is just a single line:

```
$s = 'GK52RY410 Confirmed. You have received Ksh110.00 from JANE DOE 448909294 on 3/2/15 at 7:50 PM New Tigo balance is USD110.00.Pay Bills via Tigo';
```

If you look at your output from the database, you will notice, that there are linebreaks in the string (I assume this from the paste you provided, it **might not be the case**):

```
FX67KU373 Confirmed.
You have received USD85.00 from
JANE DOE 44587398
on 4/11/14 at 5:48 PM
New Tigo balance is USD92.00.Save money on Tigo
```

So, your pattern is simple not matching, because it is only searching for *blanks* between `from` and `on`

you should use `\s+` for this, so `'/from\s+(.*?)\s+on/'`

```
from\s+(.*?)\s+on
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/2gFON56Z8GxJGq07)

Comment: `m` does not do what you think it does. If you have no `^` or `$` in your regex, `m` does nothing at all.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol - you're right. but still a `blank` does not match a linebreak, while `\s*` would.

Comment: Shouldn't there be at least one whitespace as separator? Many thanks for that link, btw!

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt most likely yes.

Answer (score -1):

Try Add g or i Option on pattern like:"/test/i"

Comment: Its not because of case sensitivity.

Comment: Remove ? From pattern. Is $s filled?